# Question with two, three right answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a little dilemma. There is simple question that came up in my actual research that I'd like to ask, but I think it's forbidden by stackexchange rules, because it has more than one correct answer. The question (from exp. particle physics) would be something along:

> What data-driven methods are there to estimate the QCD multijet background?

There are two, max. three methods that are well-known and can be described succinctly (and with references). But there might be more methods I don't know of, and these would probably be even more useful to me. I don't know all the techniques - otherwise I wouldn't be asking - so I don't know the total number of answers. But it's not open ended, in the sense that there is a small, finite number of answers.

**Usually, I'd just reformulate the question slightly and pretend I didn't know the question had multiple answers**:

> How to estimate the QCD multijet background from data?
>
> How does *the technique* work?

That's of course silly, and it makes the question less useful because I have to play dumb and can put less information in it. Someone will post an answer saying I have a misconception and explain two methods, and somebody else might post the third, so I'll eventually get what I want. I see this on Stackoverflow all the time.

(A third option: demand that the correct answer contains *all* techniques known to mankind. This is true to the word of the law, since there is only *one* right answer, but it's even more silly.)

I believe this question and its potential answer(s) are useful, yet I fear it will be closed and downvoted quickly. **So, what should I do?**

Comment: While the number of *possible* ways is non-trivial there are only a few *usual* ways---ones that won't bring on a hail of questions at a talk. Adding the work "usual" would, IMNSHO, be a good idea.

Comment: Of course, questions about unusual methods are one topic as well, but you'd be best focusing on whatever property of the analysis you are trying to optimize.

Answer (score 14):

There's nothing wrong with a question having more than one answer. Many questions on SE sites do. The problem is with open-ended, soft questions, where there's a large and expanding or unbounded set of possible answers, and there is no metric to judge one against another.

I would recommend asking your question like this:

> How to estimate the QCD multijet background from data?
>
> *(in question body)*
>
> I know of method X, Y, and Z, but these don't work for me because *(details)*. Is there a method that gets around that problem?

or

> Is there a more accurate way to estimate the QCD multijet background from data?
>
> I know of method X, Y, and Z, but those give large uncertainties. *(details)* Is there another method that does better?

or some such thing - basically, identify why you're not satisfied with existing methods and ask for a better one. The trick is to phrase it so that you're looking for a solution to a problem you have, as opposed to phrasing it as though you're just trying to collect a list.

Even if you were to ask

> What data-driven methods are there to estimate the QCD multijet background?

it'd probably be more or less okay because there is a small set of methods which could be described or summarized in one answer. Note that you don't have to require that an answer contain *all* known methods. Someone can provide an incomplete answer listing some methods, and other people can then post their own answers that build on that one.

Comment: In fact, having a small number of *working* solution from which the community can select the one most appropriate to the question is *exactly* the situation in most Stack Overflow question which are the model for the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Good answer! However I think in this case asking the general question might be more useful than addressing concrete problems in my work. The '*(details)*' are likely to be very obscure and won't help anybody in the future (a la "The *foo* fit in the 2nd iteration of my procedure does not converge when using *bar* jets"). Also I don't want to be falling into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where my concrete problems would be fixed by using a completely different approach.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the reasonable attitude and good judgement distinguishing legitimate questions which can naturally have multiple answers against (too big and not useful) list questions I appreciate and agree with too, +1 :-)

Comment: My thoughts exactly. A question can have many correct answers as long as they are indeed testably correct. As a matter of fact, those questions are probably the best ones: where you can look at things in a few different but fairly equivalent ways; this makes for better insights and more creative solutions. I think the problems mainly arise from questions that can have multiple answers, but none of them are objectively more correct than the others.